# Steps for setting up python django on Redhat4, with Apache2

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, redhat

What are the steps for installing all the dependencies needed to get python django working with Apache2 on a Redhat4 system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the Apache [apxs module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/apxs.html), which is needed for installing other modules (sudo find / -name "apxs").

If no apxs module exists then:

```
sudo yum install httpd-devel
```

For python's django module you need to install the python developer package, and its dependencies--in my case I ran these 2 install commands:

```
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Installing and configuring dgango to talk to apache is a bit complex. You need to install the mod_wsgi python module and edit/configure the apache configuration file and the wsgi.py files ([read this](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide)).

```
wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-3.3
./configure
```

Add this line in the "LoadModule" part of your apache config file (ie. something named like these: `www.vhost.conf` , `httpd.conf` , etc)

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Restart apache so it recoginizes your new changes:

```
/etc/init.d/sudo service httpd stop
/etc/init.d/sudo service httpd start
```

[Redhat Docs for installing Apache modules](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-apache-addmods.html)